# Windows Phone 7 - Upload file to FTP server

Tags: windows-phone-7, upload, ftp

Hy.

I do an application in WP7 which is connet a FTP server. I would like to upload a photo(with photochoosertask).

I wrote a PhotoChooserTask() which I could choose a photo. The program save the photo name(samplephoto01.jpg) and the photo route.
And I wrote a code which send command to FTP server:

```
    public static void Execute(String msg)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        Byte[] cmd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((msg + "\r\n").ToCharArray());
        socketEventArg.SetBuffer(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
        socket.SendAsync(socketEventArg);
    }
```

This code i can chose the photo:

```
public void SelectAndUpLoad()
    {
        PhotoChooserTask p = new PhotoChooserTask();
        p.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(pt_Completed);
        p.ShowCamera = true;
        p.Show();
    }

    void pt_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
            string PhotoPath = e.OriginalFileName;
           // MessageBox.Show(PhotoPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < library.Pictures.Count; i++)
            {
                Stream s = library.Pictures[i].GetImage();
                if (s.Length == e.ChosenPhoto.Length)
                {
                    string filename = library.Pictures[i].Name;
                    MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show(filename, "Upload?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                    if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                    {

                        Ftp.UploadFile(PhotoPath);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the code whic i would like to upload the file:

```
public static void UploadFile(string file)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Execute("STRO " + file);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

But when i use the UploadFile(); method the program answer this:

MethodAccessException was unhandled

This code:

```
.
.
 Ftp.UploadFile(PhotoPath);

                    }
                    else
                    {     //MethodAccessException
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                }
```

What was the wrong? Thank you!

---

I rewrote this code with IsolatedStorage to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < library.Pictures.Count; i++)
            {
                Stream s = library.Pictures[i].GetImage();
                if (s.Length == e.ChosenPhoto.Length)
                {
                    string filename = library.Pictures[i].Name;
                    MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show(filename, "Upload?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                    if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                    {
                        IsolatedStorageFile iss = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                        IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = iss.OpenFile(PhotoPath, FileMode.Open);
                        Ftp.UploadFile(fs, filename);
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

And the UploadFile() method:

```
    public static void UploadFile(IsolatedStorageFileStream file, string RemoteFile)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        int bytes;
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Execute("STRO " + RemoteFile);

        file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        while ((bytes = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(buffer, bytes, 0);
            socket.SendAsync(socketEventArg);
        }

    }
```

But i get an exception in this source:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = iss.OpenFile(PhotoPath, FileMode.Open);
```

The exception is: IsolatedStorageException was unhadnled.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in the line:

```
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
```

You can't open files this way on WP7. To get a stream to a file, you can either open it from the Isolated Storage (given that the file is stored there), or use the stream provided by a built-in method.

In your case, you have the stream with the property `e.ChosenPhoto`. Why don't you use it directly?

```
public static void UploadFile(Stream stream, string file)
{
    socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Execute("STRO " + file);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Then call `UploadFile` using `e.ChosenPhoto` as the first argument.