# need code for ftp in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ftp, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am developing a `windows phone 7.1 application` and I need to upload image to a `ftp client` .I have already created a ftp client . I need a code which takes the

1. ftp address
2. ftp userId
3. ftp password

Please help me I have just jumped into server side.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link:
http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ftps.php
Or you can port the silverlight ftp client:
http://silverlightftp.codeplex.com/
Also, see this question for some usefull sample code if you don't want to use a third part client:
[Windows Phone 7 - Upload file to FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617150/windows-phone-7-upload-file-to-ftp-server)

Comment: Mixx thanks for the reply but i have already tried these examples ,i need a smaller code for a mobile application

Comment: i need a free ftp library . the above links are paid or is not supported by windows phone 8.